# Диаграмма (BarChart) - ScrollView - Android

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview, scrollview

Необходимо сделать график, который на картинке (BarChart). В качестве столбцов рекомендуется использовать View, а в качестве контейнера ScrollView. Количество столбцов примерно 20000.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нельзя использовать различные библиотеки. (Поэтому предлагать использовать готовое решение из какой-нибудь библиотеки — не катит). RecyclerView не предлагать.

График должен горизонтально, корректно прокручиваться и не тормозить, следовательно, не должна быть утечка памяти, а значит, необходимо использовать переиспользование View-элементов в контейнере.

В качестве контейнера я использовал HorizontalScrollView. А теперь вопрос. Как сделать переиспользование, чтобы не было утечки? Так как HorizontalScrollView вмещает в себя только одного child (использовал LinearLayout), добавлять в layout 20000 views — это проблема. Так ещё нет возможности использовать adapter для scrollview или linearlayout, чтобы можно было воспользоваться переиспользованием getView, как в listView. Как мне быть? Кто-нибудь может помочь? Если возможно, желательно, с примером.

Comment: самому оржанизовать повторное использование. Или же рисовать на канве, без использования ScrollView вообще

Comment: Я возможно что-то упустил, а в чем проблема использовать адаптер положив в LinearLayout ListView